# Joomla user login, register, start session

Tags: php, session, joomla

I'm preparing joomla plugin/api to connect website with mobileapp. I cannot use cookies, I need to do this only by request.

So to login I can go to http://example.net/?user=aaa&pass=bbb and it creates session and returns token.

To go to user profile I can go to: http://example.net/profile?token=8asd7g... and if token matches session id in database then it sets session cookie (on php side) in Joomla framework

**Which event should I use to:**

1. check token and maintain session
2. check login, user and login/create session
3. check login, user and register user

**The second question is how:**

1. is it enought to set `$session->set('userid',$user->id);` ?
2. I create fake $response and `$app->triggerEvent('onUserLogin', array((array) $response, array('action' => 'core.login.admin')));` is it enough?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody need here is almost fnished solution. It allows users to login via user and pass taken form url or request header, it allows access to restricted parts of website based on token i url not cookie, it allows to pass params from header to JInput->get.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     API
 * @subpackage  System.sittetokenlogin
 *
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Unauthorized Access');

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');


class PlgSystemSittetokenlogin extends JPlugin
{
    public function __construct(&$subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }


    public function onUserAuthenticate()
    {
        //die('onUserAuthenticate');

    }
    public function onUserLogin()
    {//wykonuje się
        //die('onUserLogin');

    }

    public function onUserLogout()
    {//wykonuje się
        //die('onUserLogout');

    }   


    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        //wstępne ustawienie obiektów
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        if ($app->isClient('administrator')) return;
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $headers = getallheaders ();
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        //pobranie danych z rządania
        $loginToken = $headers['logintoken']; if(!$loginToken) $loginToken = $input->get->get('logintoken', '', 'STRING');
        $suser = $headers['suser']; if(!$suser) $suser = $input->get->get('suser', '', 'STRING');
        $spass = $headers['spass']; if(!$spass) $spass = $input->get->get('spass', '', 'STRING');

        if ($loginToken) // logowanie na bazie tokenu
            {
            JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user');
            $sesja = $db->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `#__session` WHERE `session_id`='.$db->quote($loginToken).' LIMIT 1')->loadObject();      
            $user = $db->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `#__users` WHERE `id`='.$db->quote($sesja->userid).' LIMIT 1')->loadObject();      

            $response = new JAuthenticationResponse();
            $response->type          = 'Joomla';
            $response->email         = $user->email;
            $response->fullname      = $user->name;
            $response->username      = $user->username;
            $response->password      = '';
            $response->status        = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS; 
            $response->error_message = null;
            //print_r($response);
            $app->triggerEvent('onUserLogin', array((array) $response, array('action' => 'core.login.site')));

            //$testuser = JFactory::getUser(); die(print_r($testuser,true));  
            }

        elseif ($suser && $spass) //logowanie na bazie loginu i hasła
            {
            $error = $app->login([
                'username' => $suser,
                'password' => $spass,
            ]);
            $user = JFactory::getUser();
            if ($user->id>0) die(JFactory::getSession()->getId());
            else die('login_error');
            }


        //przekazywanie parametrów
        $option = $headers['option']; $input->set('option',$option);
        $view = $headers['view']; $input->set('view',$view);
        $id = $headers['id']; $input->set('id',$id);
        $catid = $headers['catid']; $input->set('catid',$catid);
        $Itemid = $headers['Itemid']; $input->set('Itemid',$Itemid);
        $tmpl = $headers['tmpl'];  $input->set('tmpl',$tmpl);

        //$input->set('option','com_guru');
        //$input->set('view','gurupcategs');


    }
}
```